# Search for a folder by its name in c# without specifying the path

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to search a folder by its name. But I don't know the location of the folder.

Have to get the path of that specific folder.

How Can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the directory to search for the folder using [Directory.GetDirectories Method (String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx)

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\",
                                                 "*", 
                                                 SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

To get all drives from the computer, use [DircotoryInfo.GetDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) and then search in all of them you can try:

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
List<string> directoryList = new List<string>();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    directoryList.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(d.Name , "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
```

Comment: But what if its in D or E drive??? do I have to search for all of them separately?

Comment: @user1909204, did you check the 2nd part of the answer, You can get all the drives and then search between them

Comment: Directory.GetDirectories(d.Name , "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) while doing this its giving error "Access to the path 'D:\System Volume Information' is denied."
I checked the security setiings too they are fine..

Comment: @user1909204, you have to put a try catch block, you can't access these folders, OS prevent you from doing that, Put a try-catch block and ignore the exception, See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access

Answer (score 0):

**// Only get subdirectories that begin with the letter "p."**

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "p*");
Console.WriteLine("The number of directories starting with p is {0}.",dirs.Length);
foreach (string dir in dirs) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

[Reference - Directory.GetDirectories Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx)

If you dont know the drive then you need to search for all drives by changing the drives available on your system.

Comment: What i m actually trying to do is i have to find a folder inside D:\\Sachin_RnD_Latest\\TestResults\\SummaryReport a folder named "version", the path \\TestResults\\SummaryReport is constant but not "D:\\Sachin_RnD_Latest\", now how can I get the files contained in that version folder?

Comment: Do you have the permissions to do it?  If you don't, your program won't either.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution is using recursive search to surf all available folders and sub folders and also to jump access denied paths to have complete list of target result.