# find path of folder in c# windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to find path of a folder. Let's say folder name is `Test`. If my application is installed on `c:\drive` so in that case `Test` folder can be at any level in `c:\drive` and the page in which I need path can also be at any level in `c:\drive`.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229203/search-for-a-folder-by-its-name-in-c-sharp-without-specifying-the-path

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       string pathToDirctory = @"C:\\";
       string baseDirectory = pathToDirctory;


       string path = SearchAllFolders(pathToDirctory,"Test");


    }

    private static string SearchAllFolders(string path, string search)
    {
        string folderPath = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
                != FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
            {
                foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    if (folder.Contains("RECYCLE.BIN"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    string p = Path.GetFileName(folder);

                    if ( p.Equals(search))
                    {
                        return folder;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string f = SearchAllFolders(folder ,search);
                        if (f != null)
                        {
                            return f;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: "Test" May or may not be in "drive". it can be at any level in "C:\\drive\\"

Comment: Means you want to find folder by name in C:\\ drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the folder by name using a recursive function:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as you code in asp.net web application

```
string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(baseDirectory, "Test", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
{
    // dir will be a path of "Test" folder.
    // You will get more than one path if it found more than one folder names Test.
}
```

**baseDirectory** will store a path of a folder you installed the application.

Comment: This will throw exception `UnAuthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: It's access denie exception that you have to set permission to your folder for allow accessing.

Comment: Please also learn from here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Comment: According to your solution it will search inside "baseDirectory", but "Test" Folder may also be in parent of baseDirectory or many layer upper than baseDirectory .

Comment: According to your question, I understood that you want to find Test folder path which is in any level of application's installed path, and baseDirectory is the path you mean. Maybe I understood wrong.