# How to get a list of files and folders in the subdirectory

Tags: c#

I need to get a list of files and folders in a subdirectory.
The file list all clear, but what about a list of directories not sure

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Temp");
            Console.WriteLine("============ list of directories =============");
            foreach (var item in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("== list of subdirectories ==");
                foreach (var it in item.GetDirectories())
                    Console.WriteLine(it.Name);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("============== list of files ==============");
            foreach (var item in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a better way?

Example of directories:

```
folder1   
- folder2   
-- folder3   
-- folder4   
--- folder5
```

Comment: List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mitch Wheat suggested, there is the option `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. However, be aware that this may result in an UnauthorizedAccessException when it hits folders which it cannot access.

So the best solution for me always was to use a recursive function which can ignore inaccessible folders.

For a recursive solution, see [Ignore folders/files when Directory.GetFiles() is denied access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access) here on StackOverflow or [Folder recursion](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FolderRecursion.aspx)