# Find a file by file name

Tags: c#, filepath

What is the best way to find a file by its file name and then return its path?

e.g.

```
public string GetFilePath(string filename)
{
    // some work to get the path
    return filepath;
}
```

I have tried this but unsuccessfully

```
public string GetFileContent(string filename)
{
    DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + filename + "*.*");

    foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
    {
        string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
        return fullName;
    }
    return "found nothing";
}
```

Is there a best practice approach for finding a file by its file name on the hard drive?

Comment: Is file is placed in specific directory ??

Comment: I want it to be as dynamic as possible. In other words I want it to find any file with the same filename as the parameter provedes.

Comment: Means file would be at any place. So you have to scan complete `FileExplorer` every disk and directory.

Comment: If that's possible, yes. Question stands as before, how do I do this?

Comment: Check out this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
foreach(string file in files)
{
    if(Path.GetFileName(file).Contains("Your filename"))
    {
      do stuffs...
    }
}
```

For Performance:

```
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*",System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

string searchTerm = @"Visual Studio";

// Search the contents of each file. 
// A regular expression created with the RegEx class 
// could be used instead of the Contains method. 
// queryMatchingFiles is an IEnumerable<string>. 

var queryMatchingFiles =
from file in fileList
let fileText =Path.GetFileName(file)
where fileText.Contains(searchTerm)
select file.FullName;
```

Comment: Your can use  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882649.aspx to do it in linq

Answer (score 0):

If I was looking for a file and I did not know the location then I would use the bultin [Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362.aspx).

See the [code samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssearch) page for examples specifically the [DSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940335.aspx) code sample.

> The DSearch code sample demonstrates how to create a class for a
>   static console application to query Windows Search using the
>   Microsoft.Search.Interop assembly for ISearchQueryHelper.

Otherwise the [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) class has builtin helpers such as [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Directory.GetFiles.aspx) which will do pattern matching.

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) to **recursively** search a directory for **matching** files:

The working example below will find all of the full paths for files matching `"Hello"` in directory `"C:\"`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var files = GetFilePaths("*Hello*", "C:\\");

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFilePaths(string pattern, string directory)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(directory, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
```

**EDIT**

The following answer is better as it get's around access denied issues:

[Ignore folders/files when Directory.GetFiles() is denied access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access)