# C# searching and getting Absolute Path of Software

Tags: c#, .net, registry, console-application

I am **new to C#** and I want to create a little **Autorun Manager** in a Console Application. To do that I want to **read from the console a keyword** like "Steam" and my programm should **search on "C:\"** and in **all subdirectories** for a **folder called like my keyword** but as I say I have no Idea **how I can search in all subdirectories**.

Thats a little code sample with steam how I would write in registry

```
//filePath would be the Path of the .EXE file that was found    
string filePath = "\"C:\\Programme\\Steam\\Steam.exe\""; 
string autostartPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\";
RegistryKey autostart = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(autostartPath, true);
autostart.SetValue("Steam", filePath);
```

If someone know how to **search** in **all subdirectories** and **find** the **correct .exe file**.

I would be really **grateful** for a **code sample**.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Why don't you use a search engine before posting, make some try with the code found and finally ask for help if you have troubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively easy using `Directory.GetFiles()`:

```
string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "steam.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will search for all files matching the name `steam.exe` on C:\ and in all subdirectories, and return all the results as an array of `string`.

Note that you can use wildcards in the name, so that `"steam*.exe"` will return all files starting with `steam` with an `exe` extension.

If you need to, add `using System.IO` to the top of your class to import the `IO` namespace.

Comment: Of course we could leave the problem about Permission Exceptions for a second question IE C:\System Volume Information and others

Comment: @Steve I don't seem to see any query about permissions in the OP's question.  He asked how to search for files in sub-folders using C#.

Comment: @Steve I even dont think about permissions because I was searching for the basic code because I didn't find something usefull when I was searching.

Comment: My point was: Calling `Directory.GetFiles` on the root of C: drive will lead to an exception because the code will try to access one or more directories that are system protected. So if the OP uses this approach he/she should to plan how to handle the exceptions. But this is a bit pointless now.

Comment: @Steve Absolutely correct of course, this is likely to be a problem if the OP doesn't anticipate that circumstance.  Further to Steve's point, the OP can look here to see how to anticipate permission problems and deal with them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access