# How to request UAC in fsi and fsharp script

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I have a script:

```
open System
open System.IO

let fileSize path =
    try
        Some((new FileInfo(path)).Length)
    with
    | e ->
        printfn "%A" e
        None

let dirSize dir =
    Directory.GetFiles(dir,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    |> Array.map fileSize
    |> Array.map (Option.defaultValue 0L)
    |> Array.reduce (+)

dirSize """C:\Users\xxx\Documents""";;
```

I get a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` running it.
I try to run `cmd` or `fsi` as administrator ,but either worked.
I find a solution used in fsharp program by using `Manifest file`.
But the `--win32manifest` option can't be used in fsi(it's an option of `fsc`).
`error FS0243: Unrecognized option: '--win32manifest'`.

Is there any solution to request UAC in script?
(I know how to fix the script above by replacing the `GetFiles` method to catch the exception)

Answer (score 2):

I can say after a bit of research that is is not a .FSX issue, I was able to replicate the problem in visual studio in C# and in F# applications. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access) to a similar issue. I think the solution would be to use a folder that you do have full permissions to (anything in my documents is iffy), or use a solution like [this](http://www.fssnip.net/fp/title/Enumerate-files-without-permissions-errors) as a starting point.

Comment: I know how to fix it.... ...You may be ignore the last sentence.I want to know how to request an UAC in the script for further use.