# Parallel LINQ UnauthorizedAccessException when Aggregating results

Tags: c#, linq, exception, plinq

I am searching in parallel using `LINQ` to find pattern matching files.

```
public class ParallelLinq
{
    public IList<string> SearchFolders = new List<string>
    {
        @"C:\Windows" //can be multiple
    };

    protected virtual IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string[] searchPatterns, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        return searchPatterns.AsParallel()
            .SelectMany(searchPattern =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) //catch UnauthoizedException/IOExceptions
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
                }
            });
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Find(IList<string> patterns)
    {
        var testResultFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        if (!SearchFolders.Any() || !patterns.Any())
        {
            return testResultFiles;
        }

        testResultFiles = SearchFolders.AsParallel().Aggregate(testResultFiles, (current, folder) => current.Union(GetFiles(folder, patterns.ToArray())));

        return testResultFiles;
    }
}
```

However when I try evaluate the values I am running into `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs' is denied.`

```
var plinq = new ParallelLinq();
var res = plinq.Find(new List<string> { "*.dll" });
Console.WriteLine("Linq Count: " + res.Count());
```

While these exceptions are expected, How can we catch them and continue ahead?

Full Exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs' is denied.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at
>   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.AddSearchableDirsToStack(SearchData
>   localSearchData)    at
>   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.SelectManyQueryOperator`3.SelectManyQueryOperatorEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TOutput&
>   currentElement, Pair`2& currentKey)    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.PipelineSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork()    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work()    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object unused)    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__10_0(Object o)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean
>   userInitiatedDispose)    at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.AsynchronousChannelMergeEnumerator`1.MoveNextSlowPath()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Parallel.AsynchronousChannelMergeEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__67`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: so what you have is not catching the error? Its unclear whether you are asking if this can be optimised, or its not working at all as soon as it hits an access denied error

Comment: @MichaelRandall it's not working. It's throwing the `Exception` and returning zero results

Comment: Directory.EnumerateFiles returns IEnumerable, so "delayed" sequence, and an exception is being thrown later when sequence is being materialized (at enumerator's MoveNext). Please use this question for traversing through subfolders and avoiding inaccessible subfolders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ParallelLinq
{
    public IList<string> SearchFolders = new List<string>
    {
        @"C:\Windows" //can be multiple
    };

    private static string[] TryGetTopDirectories(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            return Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new string[0];
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetSubfolders(string path, SearchOption searchOption)
    {
        if (searchOption == SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        {
            return TryGetTopDirectories(path);
        }
        else
        {
            var topFolders = TryGetTopDirectories(path);
            return topFolders.Concat(
                topFolders.SelectMany(subFolder => GetSubfolders(subFolder, searchOption)));
        }
    }

    protected virtual ParallelQuery<string> GetFiles(string path, string[] searchPatterns, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        return GetSubfolders(path, searchOption).AsParallel()
            .SelectMany(subfolder =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return searchPatterns.SelectMany(searchPattern => Directory.EnumerateFiles(subfolder, searchPattern)).ToArray();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) //catch UnauthoizedException/IOExceptions
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
                }
            });
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Find(IList<string> patterns)
    {
        var testResultFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        if (!SearchFolders.Any() || !patterns.Any())
        {
            return testResultFiles;
        }

        testResultFiles = SearchFolders.AsParallel().Aggregate(testResultFiles, (current, folder) => current.Union(GetFiles(folder, patterns.ToArray())));

        return testResultFiles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the path 'C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs' is preventing the program from creating files. It can be resolved by adding extra permission in the folder itself.

[How to add permission to folder manually](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer)