# How can I get whether directory accessible without try&catch?

Tags: c#

Now I am about to get directories of "C:\Documents and Settings" like this:

```
var d=Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Documents and Settings")
```

Visual Studio reports an error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied.'

Well, the directory is inaccessible.

I want to get to know whether the directory about to get is accessible.

Many tutorials, just like this:`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172544/ignore-folders-files-when-directory-getfiles-is-denied-access` , are using a try&catch to avoid the error.

As we know, try&catch will slow down the speed. And also, I don't think it is the best way.

Is there any way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Trying to access a folder and being denied is not a trivial situation. It warrants a try-catch in my opinion.

Comment: It's possible in .NET Core, not possible in .NET Old. Now that .NET (Core) 5 replaces .NET Old, you can use the `EnumerationOptions` parameter to skip inaccessible entries

Comment: A try/catch is fine for a solution unless you have a high number of checks like in a loop using recursion and you are worried about execution time for example.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah! I am using the .net 5 now. Would you please tell me more about this?

Comment: @MelonNG posted it as an answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I marked it as the right answer just now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in .NET Core with the [GetDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_System_IO_EnumerationOptions_), [GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_EnumerationOptions_P), [EnumerateDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories?view=netcore-3.1) and [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1) overloads that accept the [EnumerationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=netcore-3.1) parameter:

```
var options = new EnumerationOptions { IgnoreInaccessible=true };
var files=Directory.GetDirectories(somePath,"*",options);
```

EnumerationOptions exists only in .NET Core 2.1 and later, or .NET Standard 2.1 or later. To use it with Windows Forms or WPF applications you'll have to migrate them to .NET (Core) 5 first.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Directory.Exists()` should do the trick. According to the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_Exists_System_String_) it will return `false` if the directory is not accessible.

Comment: It won't - how will the code know what the file's name ?

Comment: `Directory.Exists()` uses a plethora of catch blocks :) Well, yes, you cannot see them... You could check [FileIOPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission), which is used internally.